# Python 3.x join strings from different dictionary values in list

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I want to concatenate some strings, here's the code I have at the moment:

```
ad = {'documents':[{'id': '1', 'detectedLanguages': [{'name': 'english',
                                                     'iso6391': 'en',
                                                     'score': '1'},
                                                    {'name': 'french',
                                                     'iso6391': 'fr',
                                                     'score': '0.9'}]},
                  {'id': '2', 'detectedLanguages': [{'name': 'dutch',
                                                     'iso6391': 'hol',
                                                     'score': '1'},
                                                    {'name': 'russian',
                                                     'iso6391': 'rus',
                                                     'score': '0.9'}]}
                  ]
     }

langs = {}
for dct in ad['documents']:
    langs [str(dct['id'])] = (
        ','.join(x for detected_lang_dict in dct['detectedLanguages'] for x     in detected_lang_dict['iso6391'])
        )

print (langs)
#prints {'1': 'h,o,l,r,u,s'}
```

I want the outcome to be like {'1': 'en, fr', '2': 'hol, rus'}

Comment: SORRY - edited outcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the nested for to avoid joining each character instead of the entire string:

```
langs = {}
for dct in ad['documents']:
    langs[dct['id']] = ', '.join(d['iso6391'] for d in dct['detectedLanguages'])
print (langs)
# {'1': 'en, fr', '2': 'hol, rus'}
```

You don't need to call string on the dict key, it is already a string.

BTW, you can use a *dictionary comprehension*:

```
langs = {dct['id']: ', '.join(d['iso6391'] for d in dct['detectedLanguages']) 
                                           for dct in ad['documents']}
```